# Track onclick events

Tags: javascript

My goal is to store the total amount of clicks on links in a certain page into a variable and recall that variable when the user exits the page. Would this be a correct way of doing it?

```
window.onunload = function(){
    alert("Total Links Clicked:" + clicks(););
}

var clicks = function(){
    var clickArray = [];
    var getLinks = document.getElementsByTagName(A);

    var clickValue = getLinks.onclick = function() {
    clickArray.push("1");
    }

    var totalClicks = clickArray.length;

    return totalClicks; 
}
```

Comment: Are the links all internal links, i.e. to bookmarks on the same page.

Comment: No. Some are, some aren't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code won't work for several reasons:

- You bind the click handler in `clicks()` function and don't call `clicks()` until the page is unloaded, at which point it is too late to handle any clicks. You need to bind the click handler when the page loads.
- You can't set `.onclick` on a *list* of elements, which is what your `getLinks` variable is given it was set to the result of `getElementsByTagName()` (get elements not get element).
- You pass an undeclared variable `A` to `getElementsByTagName()`; you should pass the string `"a"`.
- You have a semicolon inside the `alert()`'s closing `)`, which is a syntax error.

You could try something like this:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var clicks = 0;

    window.onunload = function(){
        alert("Total Links Clicked:" + clicks);
    }

    function clicked() {
         clicks++;
    }

    var getLinks = document.getElementsByTagName("a");    
    for (var i = 0; i < getLinks.length; i++)
        getLinks[i].onclick = clicked;
};
```

Note that the browser may block an `alert()` during an unload event, but if you use `console.log()` instead you can see that `clicks` had the right value.

Note also that of course a click on a link to another page will cause an unload, so the click count will only be more than 1 if you have links within the current page.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/A3bkT/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sessionStorage` or `localStorage` for that.

```
if(typeof(Storage)!=="undefined")
{
   // store the clicks here
   sessionStorage.numClicks = value;
}
```

and read more on these two here : http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Answer (score 0):

Bind a global event listener and just store the count with `sessionStorage`:

```
var clicks = 0;

document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    if (event.target.nodeName == 'A') {
        window.sessionStorage.setItem('clicks', ++clicks);
    }
}, false);
```